# How to change my code to get the correct enumerate name value?

Tags: delphi, enums, delphi-7, rtti

I аm trying to get the enumeration name value using RTTI.

My objective is to get the corresponding enumerate name value in Enum1(Tsex) from the selected enumerate name value in Enum2(iterator) using a string value.

Here is the code that I have implemented. I am using Delphi 7.

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,Dialogs,typinfo;

type

 Tsex = (homme,femme);
 iterator = (H,F);

TForm1 = class(TForm)
  procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
private
 { Déclarations privées }
 public
 { Déclarations publiques }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

 {$R *.dfm}


 procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i : integer;
    OT: Tsex;
    FT: iterator;
 begin
   i:=0;
   OT := Low(Tsex);
   for FT := Low(iterator) to High(iterator) do
     if GetEnumName(TypeInfo(iterator), Ord(FT)) = 'F' then
     begin
       showmessage(GetEnumName(TypeInfo(Tsex), Ord(OT)));
     end;
     i:=i+1;
     OT:=Succ(OT);
   end;
```

When I use `H` as a string I get `homme`, but when I use `F` I also get `homme`. But it needs to be `femme`.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you the value of `OT` is during each iteration of the loop?

Comment: What purpose does I serve? Why have two enum types? There should be just one. Don't define extra enum types just to have short and long names. Use const arrays for that.

Comment: I think the point you may have missed is that when you have an enumeration, you can call the enumeration name as if it were a function to return an enumeration value, e.g. OT := TSex(i).  You only need one variable in your FormShow to do what you're doing now.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it only an idea that i got and i need it to work(self challenge), my real objective is to read from a database the string where in my database i have only abbreviation in enums ('E','F') but in my form i want to get all E corresponding values in all enums or F values.

Comment: Your proposed solution is not the way forward. You really don't want enum names F and H. Too short. Whatever your problem, this is not the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Problem:

The problem in your code is that you are missing a `begin` after `for`, and this causes increment of `i` and assignment of `OT` to happen after the iteration is complete.

What you need to change is:

```
var
  i : integer;
  OT: Tsex;
  FT: iterator;
begin
  i:=0;
  OT := Low(Tsex);
  for FT := Low(iterator) to High(iterator) do
  begin // <- Add begin here
    if GetEnumName(TypeInfo(iterator), Ord(FT)) = 'F' then
    begin
      showmessage(GetEnumName(TypeInfo(Tsex), Ord(OT)));
    end;
    i:=i+1;
    OT:=Succ(OT);
  end;
 end; // <- Add end; here
```

#### Alternative solutions:

As David has pointed out, it is better to use an array to map another set of values to your enum. Like this:

```
type
 TSex = (homme, femme);

const
 SexDBValues: array [TSex] of string =
 ('H', 'F');

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetMyEnumValue(const aDBValue: string): TSex;
var
  value: TSex;
begin
  for value := Low(TSex) to High(TSex) do
  begin
    if SameText(SexDBValues[value], aDBValue) then
    begin
      Result := value;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  value: TSex;
begin
  value := GetMyEnumValue('H');
  ShowMessage(GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TSex), Ord(value)));
end;
```

---

And when your enum type contains only two values, and is unlikely to have additional values in future, you can just use good old if-else operator:

```
function GetMyEnumValue(const aDBValue: string): TSex;
begin
  if SameText(aDBValue, 'F') then
  begin
    Result := femme;
  end else
  begin
    Result := homme;
  end;
end;
```

In few words, avoid overengineering problems.

*Note: We are using `string` to store the character value and `SameText` to compare it, as it compares text case-insensitively. Plus, it allows you to compare text of multiple characters, if in future you change your mind on how values are stored in DB.*

---

#### Advice:

I would also recommend you to consult with [Delphi Coding Style Guide](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280).

It might seem unrelated to problem, but following good practice on indentation helps to avoid such problems.

Guidelines on naming types and variables are also important. They will similarly save you in other situations.

Comment: I love your answers. Here it's a silly mistake, single/compound block. You explain that but then go on to say so much more. Excellent work!

Comment: Thanks, actually I am trying to follow your example!

Comment: @quasoft i know that is prohibited to say thanks here but really i can't  hold it, THANK YOU FOR THIS BEST ANSWER OF THE YEAR